# PowerShell script to change DWORD values in registry

Tags: powershell, windows-registry

Can someone help me create a PowerShell script that will work with Windows 10 Enterprise that changes the `DWORD` value of `ConnectionType` to `1`, and the `DWORD` value of `DeferFlags` to `4` in the user registry under `HKCU:\Network\[drive letter]`.

Here's what I tried that is not working correctly

```
$registryPath = "HKCU\Network\G"
$Name = "Connection Type"
$value = "0"
IF(!(Test-Path HKCU\Network\G))
  {
      New-Item -Path "HKCU\Network\G" -Force | Out-Null
        New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU\Network\G" -Name "Connection Type" -Value 1 `
            -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null}
             ELSE { 

     New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU\Network\G" -Name "Connection Type" -Value 1 `
        -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null}
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You should edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: It is my understanding that the pathing notation for the registery is `hive:\Key\Key\value` so start by changing your paths to `HKCU:\Network\G` (add the colon). Heres some good info on creating/updating registry keys/values: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/update-or-add-registry-key-value-with-powershell/

Comment: Thank you @Drink Some Pimp Juice IT. That worked wonderfully!

Comment: @JaciFriesen 
See [Accepting an Answer](https://i.imgur.com/OZho1tT.png) to ensure you understand how that works for the solution you find for any answers that help you resolve your problem by simply checking the little gray check box to the upper left side of the answer that resolves your problem assuming one does and turn it green to show it's the answer you accepted since that's how that is supposed to work; you ask a question, you get answers, and if you get an answer that works for your needs, you simply accept that answer.

Answer (score 3):

You almost had it but needed a little nudge so below is the PowerShell that should do what you need.

### PowerShell

```
$registryPath = "HKCU:\Network\G";
If ( !(Test-Path $registryPath) ) { New-Item -Path $registryPath -Force; };
New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name "Connection Type" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force;
New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name "DeferFlags" -Value 4 -PropertyType DWORD -Force;
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Working with Registry Entries](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-registry-entries?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: @JaciFriesen Since the community has spoken and reopened the question, I put your original logic you were using back and then added to an answer the logic you confirmed resolved your issue before the uncanny closure occurred.

Comment: Only the **`New-Item`** cmdlet needs conditional execution. You can keep **`New-Item`** within the **`If`** block, remove the **`Else`** block, then have a single pair of **`New-ItemProperty`** staements.

Comment: LOL. I almost think your dual block may be easier to scan for logic, but it also doubles the chances of typos. I'm battling low vision: Zoomed browser, huge fonts, etc. So the less I have to proofread, the better.

Comment: RE: Snow We've had about a foot & more on the way. I don't drive (vision).Live in a condo so association shovels walks. About to hike to the groacery store before the next round.